# XSL selecting a XML document is not showing information

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Why doesn't this work?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:variable name="PubDB" select="document('MSA_PublisherDatabase.XML')"/>
        <table>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$PubDB/PublisherDatabase/Publishers/Publisher"/>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Publisher">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XML file contains something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PublisherDatabase xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa">
  <Publishers>
    <Publisher Gender="Male" Appointed="MinisterialServant" Serving="Publisher">
      <Name>Fred Junior</Name>
      <Notes />
      <Availability Midweek="true" Weekend="true">
        <DatesNotAvailable />
        <DefaultExclusions />
      </Availability>
      <Assignments Attendant="true" ConductorCBS="false" ReaderCBS="true" Chairman="false" Microphones="true" PlatformAttendant="true" Prayer="true" OCLM="true" Sound="true" Student="true" Demonstrations="false">
        <CustomAssignments />
      </Assignments>
    </Publisher>
  </Publishers>
</PublisherDatabase>
```

In this instance I am expecting it to give me a list of names. Nothing is showing up.

I specifically am trying to select a document in to my XSL ..

Comment: Have a look at `xmlns="http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa"` at the beginning of your document. It means all tags are in this namespace, thus you must take it into account in your XSLT.

Comment: @potame Sorry, I don't really follow you. That is just my webpage URL. I have designed the XSL and XML file so I am using valid values. Please advise what to do.

Comment: You have set `xmlns` at the beginning, of your XML, thus you are by default is the namespace where the attached URI is `http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa`. Have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp. If you want a quick fix, remove this `xmlns` declaration and your XSLT should work properly.

Comment: @potame I don't want to change the XML document. So what changes must I make to the XSL?

Comment: @potame According to the link it says: "Note: The namespace URI is not used by the parser to look up information. The purpose of using an URI is to give the namespace a unique name. However, companies often use the namespace as a pointer to a web page containing namespace information."

Comment: @potame OK, as you say, if I remove the `xmlns` entry from the **XML** document, then it works. Bit I want to keep it in, so what changes must I make to the **XSL**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `xmlns` at the beginning, of your XML, thus you are by default is the namespace where the attached URI is `http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa`.

If you want a quick fix, remove this `xmlns` declaration and your XSLT should work properly.

Otherwise, the solution would be:

1. declare the namespace at the beginning of your stylesheet: `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msa="http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa">` (I use *msa*, but any prefix could be used)
2. change your XPath to `<xsl:apply-templates select="$PubDB/msa:PublisherDatabase/msa:Publishers/msa:Publisher"/>`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you have a *namespace problem*: The namespaces of your XSLT and your XML *do not match*.

I created a solution with a third `.XML` file:

**third.xml** is simple and only used for the XSLT to start processing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
</root>
```

Your XML file named `MSA_PublisherDatabase.XML` can stay as it is - **as desired**.

But to get your desired result, your XSLT file has to be adjusted like this to properly handle the namespace issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:msa="http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa"
                              exclude-result-prefixes="msa">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:variable name="PubDB" select="document('MSA_PublisherDatabase.XML')"/>
        <table>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$PubDB/msa:PublisherDatabase/msa:Publishers/msa:Publisher"/>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="msa:Publisher">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="msa:Name"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

After these modifications the output should be/is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Fred Junior</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you're using some Linux variant, you can apply this command (with the programs`xsltproc` and `xmlindent` installed):

```
xsltproc b.xslt b1.xml | xmlindent
```